# Simple, somewhere injective and immersion holomorphic curves

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(X, J)$ be an almost complex manifold and $u: C \to X$ be J holomorphic curve. I  confuse the following three definitions, are they equivalent?

> 1. $u$ is simple if $u$ is not multiple cover, i.e. $u$ cannot factorize as $u=v \circ \varphi $, where $\varphi: C \to C'$ is $k$-fold branch cover with $k \ge 2$, and $v: C' \to X$ is holomorphic curve such that $v$ is embedded except at a finite set.
> 2. $u$ is somewhere injective if $u^{-1}\{u(z)\} = z $  for some $z \in C$.
> 3. $u$ is immersion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) and (2) are equivalent, the proof is not obvious though (the rough idea is obvious). There is a nice blog post of Chris Wendl (called *"Somewhere injective vs. multiply covered"*), giving a general proof. Otherwise, for closed curves, see the two proofs of Proposition 2.5.1 in McDuff-Salamon's big book *"J-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology"*.

Now (2) and (3) are easily not the same, the curve can be singular... did you try looking at examples?

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your reference. I think that a unbranched  cover  of the trivial cylinder is immersion but it is not somewhere injective.